# Reading a large file in PHP 5GB FILE

Tags: php

hello i need to read a large file of 5GB, i get an error like this, Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 786432) (tried to allocate 5805810472 bytes)

```
<?php 
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','-1');

$tel = file_get_contents('result.txt');
preg_match_all('/\"telScheme\":\"(.*?)\"/s',$tel,$tels);

$out = fopen("phone.txt","a");
foreach($tels[0] as $fin){
$fin = str_replace('"', '', $fin);
fwrite($out,"$fin\n");
}
fclose($out);

?>
```

Comment: You tell PHP to read a large 5GB file into memory, and get an "out of memory" error..... what did you expect.... try reading a line at a time so you only have one line of data in memory at a time

Comment: i need a replica to my code

Comment: So you want me to write your code for you? No! But I'll point you to [fopen()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [fgets()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) and [fclose()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php)

Comment: a string can only allocate around 2GB in php, so 5GB would be too large if you even wonder why..http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORRECT WAY TOPIC END

```
<?php 
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','-1');


$handle = @fopen("result.txt", "r");
$out = fopen("phone.txt","a");

if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
    preg_match_all('/\"telScheme\":\"(.*?)\"/s',$buffer,$tels);

    foreach($tels[0] as $fin){
    $fin = str_replace('"', '', $fin);
    fwrite($out,"$fin\n");
    }

    }
    fclose($handle);
}

fclose($out);

?>
```